# Loading issues with angular 4 and both node-rdkafka and kafka-node

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, apache-kafka, angular-cli

I'm very new to web front-end development and am I bit lost with the JS/Node/Angular world when it comes to loading kafka client libraries. I considered two options to access my kafka cluster: node-rdkafka and kafka-node. However, I don't think that my problems lie with them, it seems to be a lack of knowledge about JS and/or Node or whatever. I'll explain the practical problem and come back to that notion at the end.

This is my very first foray into the JS/Node/Angular world so my knowledge about it is still very limited, please bear with any noob mistakes. I began using angular cli (1.2.3) to build my components, services, etc. All was well until I tried to load node-rdkafka: the readme instructs me to use "require" instead of "import", and that was not found.

Through some research I managed to get 'require' working (I think) by altering the typings.d.ts file to be like this:

```
declare var module: NodeModule;
interface NodeModule {
  id: string;
}
declare var require: NodeRequire;
```

And tsconfig.app.json to include this:

```
"types": [
  "node"
]
```

Inside compilerOptions.

The application compiles and "const kafka = require('node-rdkafka')" begins to load the library. However, there's a bug in one of its dependencies, node-bindings. I found out that there's already a fix so I changed its version to the latest commit, just to meet a new error which was already reported but never answered:

https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-bindings/issues/34

I also get the following warnings:

```
WARNING in ./~/bindings/bindings.js
81:22-40 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

WARNING in ./~/bindings/bindings.js
81:43-53 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
```

I tried looking into node-bindings code and found out that it requires 'fs' and 'path', and that these requires are returning "undefined" in my case. Since there are people that use node-rdkafka right now without problems, I think the problem may be with my environment, but I wasted hours upon hours on this without success.

Then I tried using kafka-node instead, and also landed into problems. First, it was the "BufferMaker" dependency that depended on "Should" that was not installed by npm and I don't know why. I manually installed the required version with npm using --save-dev and then my own code compiled but with these warnings:

```
WARNING in ./~/optional/optional.js
6:11-26 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

WARNING in ./~/node-zookeeper-client/lib/jute/index.js
771:20-47 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
```

And now I get this error at runtime that no one else on the internet seems to have:

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "."
    at webpackMissingModule (index.js:771)
    at Object.<anonymous> (index.js:771)
    at Object.../../../../node-zookeeper-client/lib/jute/index.js (index.js:781)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 8ee5092…:54)
    at Object.<anonymous> (index.js:24)
    at Object.../../../../node-zookeeper-client/index.js (index.js:917)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 8ee5092…:54)
    at Object.<anonymous> (zookeeper.js:3)
    at Object.../../../../kafka-node/lib/zookeeper.js (zookeeper.js:474)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 8ee5092…:54)
```

It does not seem possible to me that everyone has these problems since only a handful of people complain about the node-rdkafka issue and I couldn't find anyone else with the kafka-node issue.

So, besides needing a solution to access a kafka cluster with JS, my real question is: is there any incompatibility between Angular 4 or Angular CLI and code that uses require? Am I mixing legacy code with current code or anything like that?

Any pointer to a solution will be very welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey Carlos, any luck on this? Stuck exactly on the same step as you, using kafka-node. Any good leads? Cheers!

Comment: Hi! I just answered the question with my latest findings. I'll soon try the kafka-rest route, I couldn't find a better (and still cheap) alternative. Let me know what you decide too!

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I gathered from the devs: these libraries are wrappers based on an official C implementation. Thus, its not possible to use them in web clients. It's possible to use them in servers though, since you would be able to build it for your specific platform. It would also be ok if you have control over the client's platforms.

What I plan to do is to use [Confluent's Kafka REST Proxy](https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka-rest/docs/index.html) which exposes kafka channels in a REST interface. Here's the specific project in the platform:

https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-rest

And there's a node client:

https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-rest-node

I've not tried it yet, though. It seems to be linux-compatible only.